# "Unable to connect to: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release" when running 'mvn site'

Tags: spring, maven, maven-site-plugin

I'm trying to use the maven-site-plugin to generate a site for my project.  For now, I've just added the plugin and am running `mvn site` from the root of my multi-module project.

I'm seeing the following error in the the log every time i run `mvn site`.

```
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Unable to connect to: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release
```

The `Unable to connect to` message is repeated dozens of times in the log.

The project's poms can be found here: https://github.com/justinhrobbins/FlashCards_App  but as stated above, i have just added the plugin the pom for maven-site-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</plugin>
```

Even though I'm seeing those errors, the build suceeds and i do see dependencies on the generated site's Dependency Convergence page.

I tried [Googling](https://www.google.com/#q=%22Unable+to+connect+to%3a+http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release%22) the error but only found some CI build logs with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the site plugin skip generating repository locations for all of your dependencies with:

> -Ddependency.locations.enabled=false

That flag will make your error go away (and speed up site generation a ton)

You will no longer get a link to the repository where the binary is hosted on the reports page, but you will still get the rest of the dependency information.

As to *why* that error is happening, the [SpringSource repo](http://repo.springsource.org/) is actually an [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/) server.  It's very likely a wire is getting crossed somewhere between what the maven-site-plugin thinks it needs for report generation and Artifactory.

P.S. This flag speeds up site generation even further.

> -Ddependency.details.enabled=false

It turns off super detailed examination of dependency jars. (number of classes, number of packages, file size, etc)